# How to differentiate between Students and Teachers?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-edu

In the [Microsoft Teams client SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-context) there is a `userLicenseType` property which we can use to determine if the user is a `student` or a `teacher`.

We want to do the same thing in our backend code to make sure that Students aren't running processes they shouldn't be, but we can't find an easy way of getting this same information from Microsoft Graph.

Does anyone know a way we can find this information? We were hoping it might be available through the access token or through `/v1.0/education/me/` or `/v1.0/me/` endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

The [educationUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/educationuser?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) has a similar property called `primaryRole`. You can retrieve this using [`/v1.0/education/me`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationuser-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs). Here is an example result:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#education/me/$entity",
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "displayName": "Megan Bowen",
    "givenName": "Megan",
    "surname": "Bowen",
    "userPrincipalName": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
    "userType": "Member",
    "id": "48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038",
    "primaryRole": "teacher"
}
```

Comment: Is this always there for EDU tenants? - I´ve got 3 EDU schools I created at [link](https://demos.microsoft.com) and when I call this endpoint the primaryRole field isn´t returned for either a teacher or a student.

Comment: No, it is only populated if Microsoft School Data Sync or some equivalent tool has been run.  That said, we have lots of customers who do not use the most obvious license type, so you might find all students have the teachers license of vice versa in some institutions.  Code behavior based on licensing is very fragile.

Comment: Thanks, that´s good to know. Should we presume this fragile nature also for the userLicenseType provided by the Microsoft Teams SDK? Is there any other suggestions of solving what we are trying to achieve here in regards to hiding specific functionality for students?

Comment: I believe the `userLicenseType` is leveraging the same licensing data so I would consider it just as fragile. I need to think through alternatives but I suspect the best model here would be to first check `primaryRole` and then fall back to checking the license type of it isn't populated.